# Kernels and Images of Commutative operators and the restriction map characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $T_{i} : V \rightarrow V$ be wo commutative to each other linear
>   operators, i.e., $$ T_{1}\circ T_{2} = T_{2} \circ T_{1}$$ as maps,
>   Namely, $$ T_{1}(T_{2}(\mathbf{v})) = T_{2}(T_{1}(\mathbf{v})) ~~~~
>  (\forall \mathbf{v} \in V).$$
>
> a) Show that both $$\text{Ker}(T_{2}), ~~~ \text{Im}(T_{2})$$ are
>    $T_{1}$-invariant subspaces of $V$.
>
> Give an example to show the necessity of the commutativity assumption
>   on $T_{i}$.
>
> b) Let $\lambda_2 \in F$ be an eigenvalue of $T_2$. Show that the
>   eigenspace $V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$ of $T_2$ is $T_1$ invariant.
>
> c) Suppose that characteristic polynomial of $T_1$ $$p_{T_1}(x) =
>  (x-a_1)(x-a_2) \cdots (x-a_n) ~~~\text{ for some }a_i \in F$$ By
>   considering the restriction operator $T_1|V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$, show
>   that there is a common eigenvector $\mathbf{w} \neq 0$ of both $T_i$
>   such that $$T_i(\mathbf{w}) = \lambda_i\mathbf{w} ~~\text{ for some
>  eigenvalue } \lambda_i \text{ of } T_i$$

**Hi readers, this is a long question, my main question is part c, in which i have some troubles understanding and resolving due to the sheer amount of info packed in a little question. It is a long question, so for anyone willing, please read my part c and instruct me on it! (part a, b can be skipped as its just a preclusion to the last part)**

a) There are two ways to approach.

First way is to prove that if $x \in ker(T_2)$, then show that $T_1(x) \in ker(T_2)$.

Second way is to show that $T_1(ker(T_2)) \subseteq ker(T_2)$.

Similarly, we can use the same idea to show $\text{Im}(T_2)$ is invariant under $T_1$.

b) Let $f(x) = x, g(x) =x - \lambda_2$ be two polynomials. Then   by our exercise theorem, we have $f(T_1) = T_1$ and $g(T_2) = T_2 - \lambda_2 I_V$. Hence they are commutative.

Once we show that $T_1$ and $T_2- \lambda_2 I_V$ are commutative to each other, we see that by part a) that $ker(T_2-\lambda_2 I_V)$ is an invariant subspace under $T_1$. And since $ker(T_2-\lambda_2 I_V) = V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$, we are done.

Note that we need to prove that : Let $f(x),g(x) \in F[x]$ be polynomials, let $T_i: V \to V$ be two linear operators commutative to each other, Show that $$f(T_1) \circ g(T_2) = g(T_2) \circ f(T_1)$$ as linear operators on $V$.

***c)***

> Since $V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$ is $T_1$ invariant by part b, the
>   restriction map $$T^{'} = T_1|V_{\lambda_2}(T_2):V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)
>  \to V_{\lambda_2}(T_2) $$ is a well defined linear operator on
>    $V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$.
>
> Note by characteristic polynomial of the restriction operator, we know
>   that $$p_{T_1}(x) = q(x)p_{T_1|V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)}(x)~~~\text{ for
>  some polynomial } q(x) \in F[x]$$
>
> Equate the equation with $0$ and we take a root of
>    $p_{T_1|V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)}(x)=0$. We will get a root say $a_1$ WLOG
>   and of course this $a_1$ is also a root of $p_{T_1}$. So $a_1$ is an
>   eigenvalue of $T_1$ and of $T_1|V_{\lambda_2}(T_2) = T^{'}$.
>
> Now note that $$T^{'} : V_{\lambda_2}(T_2) \to V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$$
>
> So if $a_1$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{'}$, we let $\mathbf{w}$ be the
>   corresponding eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $a_1$. In
>    which case we have $$T^{'}(\mathbf{w}) = a_1\mathbf{w} ~~~\text{ where
>  } \mathbf{w} \in V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$$
>
> Then since $\mathbf{w} \in V_{\lambda_2}(T_2)$, it means
>    $T_2(\mathbf{w}) = \lambda_2(\mathbf{w})$.
>
> And from earlier we have $$T^{'}(\mathbf{w}) = a_1\mathbf{w} =
>  T_1(\mathbf{w}) ~~\text{ since we mentioned }a_1 \text{ is also be an
>  eigenvalue of } T_1$$ This is because by the definition of the
>   restriction map, we must have $T^{'}(\mathbf{w}) = T_1(\mathbf{w})$.